# For Loop Error in Tweepy IDs of followers for multiple users

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, tweepy

I have the following for loop to generate two lists:

**A.** **ids:** the IDs of followers' accounts of a User

**B.** **handles:** the User handle so that I can trace back to which handle each follower belongs two

The code is using two random users so that I can track problems easily:

```
import tweepy
import time

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

users = ['x', 'y']
api = tweepy.API(auth)
ids = []
handles = []
for user in users:
    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name= user).pages():
        ids.extend(page)
        time.sleep(60)
        for userids in ids:
            handles.append(user)
```

When I run the for loop however I get an error:

In `ids` I have the correct amount of followers

In `handles` however, my total length is wrong

What am I doing wrong? I want to simply connect each ID to the account in my list that they are following.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to build a `DataFrame` from two lists of different length. Maybe I'm wrong but it's not obvious since you did not provide a reproductible example.

In this case it will produce an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

handles = ['foo', 'bar', 'doe']
ids = [1,2]

followers_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'handle': handles,
     'ids': ids})

# ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

If you want to do that you can use this trick.

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'handle': handles}),
           pd.DataFrame({'ids': ids})], 
           axis=1)

#   handle  ids
# 0    foo  1.0
# 1    bar  2.0
# 2    doe  NaN
```

Comment: Hi Romain, thanks for answering. I updated the question so hopefully it's clearer.

My question is, how can I avoid getting a list of two different lengths?

They should be theoretically the same, but I don't understand where the error is coming from!